# How can I pass along the Page Number in a HyperLinkField in a GridView?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have gridview that I am using paging on.  I want to pass along the current page in a asp:Hyperlink so I can send them back to the current page when they are done viewing the details of a record.  Is this possible? If it is how can I do this?

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdObitList" runat="server" allowpaging="true"
            PageSize="10" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="grdClass" 
                BorderStyle="None" GridLines="None" CellSpacing="2" >
            <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <PagerSettings Position="Bottom" FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" Mode="NumericFirstLast"  />
               <Columns>     
                   <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Name" DataTextField="obit_fullname" DataNavigateUrlFields="obit_id" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="obitDisplay.aspx?oid={0}" />                                     
                   <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Date" DataField="obit_dod" DataFormatString="{0:d/M/yyyy}" />
                   <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Resident Of" DataField="obit_resident" />
                   <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Funeral Home" DataField="obit_funeralhome" />
               </Columns>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is converting it to a template column, that way you can use normal databind syntaxt to get to it (<%#)